# classe não carrega fora do require usando autoload

Tags: php, php-7

Tenho a página abaixo:

```
<?php 
  require_once '../config.php'; 
  require_once 'config.php'; 
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>

        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title><?php echo $constantes->getTituloSite(); ?> - Administração - Login</title>

    </head>

    <body>

        <?php 
            if (isset ($_SESSION["login"])) require_once "home.php";
            else {

                 echo '<div id=login>

                            <form action="?" method="post">
                                <input type="hidden" name="logar" />
                                <input type="text" name="login" id="login" required placeholder="Usuário" />
                                <input type="password" name="senha"  id="senha" required placeholder="Senha" />

                                <input type="submit" value="Entrar" />

                            </form>

                        </div>';
            } 



            if (isset($_POST["logar"])) {

                print_r($_POST);

                $administradoresDao = new AdministradoresDao();

                $administradoresDao->buscarTodos ("WHERE login='" . $_POST["login"] . "' AND senha = '" . $_POST["senha"] . "'");

                $administradoresModelos = new AdministradoresModelos();


            }
        ?>

    </body>

</html>
```

Estou tendo o seguinte problema:

Note que tem 2 `configs` requeridas no início.

No meio da página, perceba que eu tenho um

```
$administradoresDao = new AdministradoresDao();
```

A primeira config.php requerida traz acesso ao banco dentre outras coisas.

Já a segunda traz somente:

```
<?php

    use classes\mvc\modelos\AdministradoresModelos;
    use classes\mvc\modelos\AdministradoresDao;
?>
```

O problema é o seguinte:

Quando eu coloco o bloco:

```
if (isset($_POST["logar"])) {
```

Dentro da página `config.php` de forma baixo:

```
<?php

    use classes\mvc\modelos\AdministradoresModelos;
    use classes\mvc\modelos\AdministradoresDao;

    if (isset($_POST["logar"])) {

        print_r($_POST);

        $administradoresDao = new AdministradoresDao();

        $administradoresDao->buscarTodos ("WHERE login='" . $_POST["login"] . "' AND senha = '" . $_POST["senha"] . "'");

        $administradoresModelos = new AdministradoresModelos();


    }; 
?>
```

A classe é carregada normalmente.

Mas se eu deixar onde está ou, pasme, colocar abaixo do require da mesma classe, dá que a classe não foi carregada!

Onde está o erro?

Comment: onde vc faz o require do autoload?

Comment: na raiz... usando composer. Topo assim, o arquivo config é achado normalmente pois se eu colocar o objeto lá dentro a casse carrega, Mas obviavemente dá erro pois ainda não tenho os dados do formulário!

Comment: então, o use é no contexto do arquivo, acho que se vc colocar ele dentro do require não vai rolar mesmo

Comment: pois é, resolvi jogando pra fora e removendo o include. No entanto, a no require anterior tem use e funciona de boa na pagina!

Comment: onde exatamente? no arquivo que você colocou como exemplo você só instanciou duas classes...

Comment: 2 requires de config.php, certo? Um, o de cima, está na raiz e também tem a clausula use. Esse eu posso chamar tranquilamente um objeto cuja use esteja  nela. Mas o config de baixo não consigo. Então tive que chamar a use diretamente no body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seu código original você não tem as declarações `use`.

Para que você instancie uma classe, ou o nome completo dela (namespace + nome da classe) deve ser utilizado, ou você deve utilizar o `use` para poder utilizar apenas o nome da classe (sem namespace).

TL;DR: Adicione as declarações `use` no código original, no início do arquivo.

Comment: Vinicius. Tem sim mano! Está dento da config.php que é a segunda requrida no incio d pagina que tem os 2 uses lá!

Comment: Confia: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php
Declarações `use` são por arquivo. Você ao menos testou a sugestão?